# Index Match / Lookup

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

In the below linked g sheet, i am trying to reference the datasource on the left.

Whereby there is a list of vehicle registration numbers on the left and a date range  across the top withe the driver name used as the value.

Table 1 refers to where i am trying to then view which vehicle each driver used on each day. (I have input the results to help with the explaination.

My attempts started with this in O6 `=INDEX(B6:K15,MATCH(M6,A4:A15,1),MATCH(O3,A5:K5,1))`

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please?

Russ

[View Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dtK6VCA8WBHWCLEmatJbJUd5m04f1LVzYbMaIkWcJDc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`=INDEX($A$6:$A$15,MATCH($M6,OFFSET($A$6:$A$15,0,MATCH(O$3,$B$5:$K$5,0)),0))`

**Explanation**

1. The `MATCH(O$3,$B$5:$K$5,0)` part is figuring out what column the date is in and returning the index number in relation to the table's range.
2. That is contained inside `OFFSET($A$6:$A$15,0,MATCH(O$3,$B$5:$K$5,0))` which is getting a reference to the column of driver names on that date. It does this by taking the table's first column, and offsetting it by the index we found in step 1.
3. Then that is contained in `MATCH($M6,OFFSET($A$6:$A$15,0,MATCH(O$3,$B$5:$K$5,0))`. This is using that column reference from step 2, looking for the row containing the driver name we're interested in, and returning that row's index.
4. Finally you have that complete formula. It's a simple Index/Match which takes the range in the first column which contains the list of vehicles, and returns the value at the row index we found in step 3.